# WPF tab - Created a Tab control as user control

Tags: wpf

i created a user control that contains a tab control with 3 tab items. now will it be possible to add or delete a tab, change the tab item name, add text,label,command button to tabs?

Comment: Have you bound it to a `ViewModel`? If so you can do it ether by your `VM` programmatically adding and removing tab items or if you do not require dynamic tab items than you can create them as hidden and then using `DataTriggers` you can unveil them.

Comment: What was your original strategy for adding, deleting tabs when you when you developed the control?  Need more info.

Comment: I am about to use tab in more places, i.e many forms where there may be a requirement to have 1 tab item at a place and many in another form. i am new to WPF. so i am not aware of much options. i am just creating forms as of now as coding i will be doing later.